# How to remove a UITextField from a cell, when a row is selected?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios5

I've added a `UITextField` to cell whenever any row of `UITableView` is first time selected, now i want to remove that text field when row get selected second time.

Any suggestion or sample code will be appreciated. 
Thanks!!

Code for adding Text field in cell: in **cellForAtIndexPath** method

```
 if (indexPath.row == selectedRow)
            {

                  numOfBottles =[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240,9.0f,50, 25)];
                    numOfBottles.tag = indexPath.row;

                    [numOfBottles setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
                    [numOfBottles setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
                    [numOfBottles setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
                    [numOfBottles setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
                    [numOfBottles setBackground:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_dropdown_normal.png"]];
                    [numOfBottles setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f]];
                    [numOfBottles setDelegate:self];

                    NSString* quantity = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[subtotalObj.qtyArray objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row - 1)]];

                    [numOfBottles setText:quantity];
                    [numOfBottles setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
                    [numOfBottles setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
                    numOfBottles.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
                    numOfBottles.tag = indexPath.row;
                    [cell.contentView addSubview:numOfBottles];
                    [numOfBottles release];

            }
```

in **didSelectedRowAtIndexPath**

```
selectedRow = indexPath.row;
[mainTable reloadData];
```

Comment: Can you try to explain better what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: Show us what have you tried before, for example a code where you add `UITextField` to cell.

Comment: @TomaszWojtkowiak, I've edited my question, now if that row get selected second time i've to delete TextField that was added when row first time selected.

Comment: @timjver, yes a row from `UITableView`, i've edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend you to create own UITableViewCell subclass.
In this class add this UITextView object and, it the method `- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated` show/hide your textField.

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    [textField setHidden:!textField.hidden]; //this alternately show and hide textField
}
```

Comment: my TL gave instructions that don't use custom UITableViewCell, now what can i do?

Comment: You can do this in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, where you can use `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to get your cell, but in my opinion, better choice is to encapsulate this code in specialised object.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get this by giving the model-objects you used to fill the cells a integer variable. This variable gets incremented by 1 each time the user selects that cell.

Then in the – tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: method (or however it is called in your app) you can make something like that:

```
if (selectedCellModel.selectCnt == 1) {
    //create the text field
} else if (selectedCellModel.selectCnt == 2) {
    //delete the text field
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just hide it?

```
[yourTextField setHidden:YES];
```

Or if the textField is a subview of the tableview cell just remove it.

```
[yourTextField removeFromSuperview];
```